# Spring Boot - Cannot determine embedded database driver class for database type NONE

Tags: java, google-app-engine, jpa, spring-data, spring-boot

This is the error that is thrown when trying to run my web app:

```
[INFO] WARNING: Nested in org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.orm.jpa.HibernateJpaAutoConfiguration': Injection of autowired dependencies failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: private javax.sql.DataSource org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.orm.jpa.JpaBaseConfiguration.dataSource; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'dataSource' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/jdbc/DataSourceAutoConfiguration$NonEmbeddedConfiguration.class]: Instantiation of bean failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanDefinitionStoreException: Factory method [public javax.sql.DataSource org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.jdbc.DataSourceAutoConfiguration$NonEmbeddedConfiguration.dataSource()] threw exception; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Cannot determine embedded database driver class for database type NONE. If you want an embedded database please put a supported one on the classpath.:
    [INFO] org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Cannot determine embedded database driver class for database type NONE. If you want an embedded database please put a supported one on the classpath.
    [INFO]  at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.jdbc.DataSourceProperties.getDriverClassName(DataSourceProperties.java:91)
    [INFO]  at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.jdbc.DataSourceAutoConfiguration$NonEmbeddedConfiguration.dataSource(DataSourceAutoConfiguration.java:100)
    [INFO]  at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    [INFO]  at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    [INFO]  at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    [INFO]  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    [INFO]  at com.google.appengine.tools.development.agent.runtime.Runtime.invoke(Runtime.java:115)
    [INFO]  at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.SimpleInstantiationStrategy.instantiate(SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java:166)
    [INFO]  at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver$3.run(ConstructorResolver.java:580)
    [INFO]  at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    [INFO]  at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(ConstructorResolver.java:577)
    [INFO]  at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1094)
    [INFO]  at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:989)
    [INFO]  at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:504)
    [INFO]  at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:475)
    [INFO]  at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:304)
    [INFO]  at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:228)
    [INFO]  at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:300)
    [INFO]  at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:195)
    [INFO]  at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.findAutowireCandidates(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1017)
    [INFO]  at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:960)
    [INFO]  at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:858)
    [INFO]  at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:480)
    [INFO]  at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InjectionMetadata.inject(InjectionMetadata.java:87)
    [INFO]  at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessPropertyValues(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:289)
    [INFO]  at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1185)
    [INFO]  at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:537)
    [INFO]  at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:475)
    [INFO]  at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:304)
    [INFO]  at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:228)
    [INFO]  at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:300)
    [INFO]  at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:195)
    [INFO]  at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(ConstructorResolver.java:370)
    [INFO]  at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1094)
    [INFO]  at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:989)
    [INFO]  at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:504)
    [INFO]  at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:475)
    [INFO]  at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:304)
    [INFO]  at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:228)
    [INFO]  at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:300)
    [INFO]  at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:195)
    [INFO]  at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.getBean(AbstractApplicationContext.java:973)
    [INFO]  at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:750)
    [INFO]  at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:482)
    [INFO]  at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:683)
    [INFO]  at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:313)
    [INFO]  at org.springframework.boot.builder.SpringApplicationBuilder.run(SpringApplicationBuilder.java:142)
    [INFO]  at org.springframework.boot.legacy.context.web.SpringBootContextLoaderListener.initWebApplicationContext(SpringBootContextLoaderListener.java:60)
    [INFO]  at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener.contextInitialized(ContextLoaderListener.java:106)
    [INFO]  at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.ContextHandler.startContext(ContextHandler.java:548)
    [INFO]  at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.Context.startContext(Context.java:136)
    [INFO]  at org.mortbay.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.startContext(WebAppContext.java:1250)
    [INFO]  at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.ContextHandler.doStart(ContextHandler.java:517)
    [INFO]  at org.mortbay.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.doStart(WebAppContext.java:467)
    [INFO]  at org.mortbay.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:50)
    [INFO]  at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.HandlerWrapper.doStart(HandlerWrapper.java:130)
    [INFO]  at org.mortbay.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:50)
    [INFO]  at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.HandlerWrapper.doStart(HandlerWrapper.java:130)
    [INFO]  at org.mortbay.jetty.Server.doStart(Server.java:224)
    [INFO]  at org.mortbay.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:50)
    [INFO]  at com.google.appengine.tools.development.JettyContainerService.startContainer(JettyContainerService.java:249)
    [INFO]  at com.google.appengine.tools.development.AbstractContainerService.startup(AbstractContainerService.java:306)
    [INFO]  at com.google.appengine.tools.development.AutomaticInstanceHolder.startUp(AutomaticInstanceHolder.java:26)
    [INFO]  at com.google.appengine.tools.development.AbstractModule.startup(AbstractModule.java:79)
    [INFO]  at com.google.appengine.tools.development.Modules.startup(Modules.java:88)
    [INFO]  at com.google.appengine.tools.development.DevAppServerImpl.doStart(DevAppServerImpl.java:254)
    [INFO]  at com.google.appengine.tools.development.DevAppServerImpl.access$000(DevAppServerImpl.java:47)
    [INFO]  at com.google.appengine.tools.development.DevAppServerImpl$1.run(DevAppServerImpl.java:212)
    [INFO]  at com.google.appengine.tools.development.DevAppServerImpl$1.run(DevAppServerImpl.java:210)
    [INFO]  at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    [INFO]  at com.google.appengine.tools.development.DevAppServerImpl.start(DevAppServerImpl.java:210)
    [INFO]  at com.google.appengine.tools.development.DevAppServerMain$StartAction.apply(DevAppServerMain.java:277)
    [INFO]  at com.google.appengine.tools.util.Parser$ParseResult.applyArgs(Parser.java:48)
    [INFO]  at com.google.appengine.tools.development.DevAppServerMain.run(DevAppServerMain.java:219)
    [INFO]  at com.google.appengine.tools.development.DevAppServerMain.main(DevAppServerMain.java:210)
```

I believe I have the right combination of `datanucleus-appengine` and `datanucleus` jars:

> 2.1: Requires DataNucleus 3.1.x (core, api-jdo, api-jpa, enhancer). Requires SDK 1.6.4+ Note that this release of Datanucleus is no longer
>   supported by the DataNucleus project

**JPA App Config:**

```
@Configuration
@EnableJpaRepositories("demo.core.entity")
@EnableTransactionManagement
class JpaApplicationConfig {
    private static final Logger logger = Logger
            .getLogger(JpaApplicationConfig.class.getName());
    @Bean
    public AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean entityManagerFactory() {
        logger.info("Loading Entity Manager...");
        LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean factory = new LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean();
        factory.setPersistenceUnitName("transactions-optional");
        return factory;
    }
    @Bean
    public PlatformTransactionManager transactionManager() {
        logger.info("Loading Transaction Manager...");
        JpaTransactionManager txManager = new JpaTransactionManager();
        txManager.setEntityManagerFactory(entityManagerFactory().getObject());
        return txManager;
    }
    @Bean
    public PersistenceExceptionTranslator persistenceExceptionTranslator() {
        return new OpenJpaDialect();
    }
}
```

**Application.java**

```
@Configuration
@ComponentScan
@EnableAutoConfiguration
@RestController
public class Application {

    private static final EntityManagerFactory INSTANCE =
            Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory("transactions-optional");

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(Application.class, args);
    }

    @RequestMapping("/")
    public String home() {
        return "Hello World";
    }

}
```

**POM:**

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="...">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>org.demohq</groupId>
    <artifactId>demo-boot</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>war</packaging>

    <name>demo-boot</name>
    <description>Demo project</description>

    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>1.1.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT</version>
    </parent>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-actuator</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-tomcat</artifactId>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-legacy</artifactId>
            <version>1.1.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT</version>
        </dependency>
        <!--<dependency>-->
            <!--<groupId>net.kindleit</groupId>-->
            <!--<artifactId>gae-runtime</artifactId>-->
            <!--<version>${gae.version}</version>-->
            <!--<type>pom</type>-->
            <!--<scope>provided</scope>-->
        <!--</dependency>-->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-aspects</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <!--<dependency>-->
            <!--<groupId>org.hsqldb</groupId>-->
            <!--<artifactId>hsqldb</artifactId>-->
            <!--<scope>runtime</scope>-->
        <!--</dependency>-->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.google.appengine</groupId>
            <artifactId>appengine-api-labs</artifactId>
            <version>${gae.version}</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.google.appengine</groupId>
            <artifactId>appengine-api-stubs</artifactId>
            <version>${gae.version}</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.google.appengine</groupId>
            <artifactId>appengine-testing</artifactId>
            <version>${gae.version}</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <!-- DataNucleus -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.datanucleus</groupId>
            <artifactId>datanucleus-api-jpa</artifactId>
            <version>${datanucleus.jpa.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.datanucleus</groupId>
            <artifactId>datanucleus-core</artifactId>
            <version>${datanucleus.jpa.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.datanucleus</groupId>
            <artifactId>datanucleus-enhancer</artifactId>
            <version>${datanucleus.jpa.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.google.appengine.orm</groupId>
            <artifactId>datanucleus-appengine</artifactId>
            <version>${datanucleus.version}</version>
            <!-- Need to exclude the enhancer since it interfere with the enhancer plugin. -->
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.datanucleus</groupId>
                    <artifactId>datanucleus-enhancer</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.jdo</groupId>
            <artifactId>jdo-api</artifactId>
            <version>3.0.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.geronimo.specs</groupId>
            <artifactId>geronimo-jpa_2.0_spec</artifactId>
            <version>1.1</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- OpenJPA -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.openjpa</groupId>
            <artifactId>openjpa-persistence</artifactId>
            <version>2.3.0</version>
        </dependency>


    </dependencies>

    <properties>
        <start-class>demo.Application</start-class>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <project.reporting.outputEncoding>UTF-8</project.reporting.outputEncoding>
        <java.version>1.7</java.version>
        <m2eclipse.wtp.contextRoot>/</m2eclipse.wtp.contextRoot>
        <datanucleus.jpa.version>3.1.1</datanucleus.jpa.version>
        <datanucleus.version>2.1.2</datanucleus.version>
        <gae.version>1.8.8</gae.version>
        <gae.home>${settings.localRepository}/com/google/appengine/appengine-java-sdk/${gae.version}/appengine-java-sdk/appengine-java-sdk-${gae.version}</gae.home>
        <gae.application.version>test</gae.application.version>
        <!--<org.springframework-version>4.0.5.RELEASE</org.springframework-version>-->
    </properties>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
            <!--
            <plugin>
                <groupId>net.kindleit</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-gae-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>0.9.6</version>
                <dependencies>
                    <dependency>
                        <groupId>net.kindleit</groupId>
                        <artifactId>gae-runtime</artifactId>
                        <version>${gae.version}</version>
                        <type>pom</type>
                    </dependency>
                </dependencies>
            </plugin>
            -->
            <plugin>
                <groupId>com.google.appengine</groupId>
                <artifactId>appengine-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>${gae.version}</version>
                <configuration>
                    <enableJarClasses>false</enableJarClasses>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-release-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <goals>gae:deploy</goals>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.tomcat.maven</groupId>
                <artifactId>tomcat6-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.0</version>
                <configuration>
                    <path>/</path>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.datanucleus</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-datanucleus-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>${datanucleus.jpa.version}</version>
                <configuration>
                    <api>JPA</api>
                    <!--<mappingIncludes>**/entity/*.class</mappingIncludes>-->
                    <verbose>true</verbose>
                </configuration>
                <dependencies>
                    <dependency>
                        <groupId>org.datanucleus</groupId>
                        <artifactId>datanucleus-core</artifactId>
                        <version>${datanucleus.jpa.version}</version>
                    </dependency>
                </dependencies>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <phase>compile</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>enhance</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

    <profiles>
        <!-- We can configure our integration server to activate this profile and 
            perform gae:deploy, thus uploading latest snapshot to the http://1.latest.<applicationName>.appspot.com 
            automatically -->
        <profile>
            <id>integration-build</id>
            <properties>
                <gae.application.version>stage</gae.application.version>
            </properties>
        </profile>

        <!-- This profile will activate automatically during release and upload 
            application to the http://2.latest.<applicationName>.appspot.com (We might 
            want to set the 2nd version as our applications Default version to be accessible 
            at http://<applicationName>.appspot.com) -->
        <profile>
            <id>release-build</id>
            <activation>
                <property>
                    <name>performRelease</name>
                    <value>true</value>
                </property>
            </activation>

            <properties>
                <!-- During release, set application version in appengine-web.xml to 
                    2 -->
                <gae.application.version>release</gae.application.version>
            </properties>
        </profile>
    </profiles>

    <repositories>
        <repository>
            <id>spring-snapshots</id>
            <name>Spring Snapshots</name>
            <url>http://repo.spring.io/snapshot</url>
            <snapshots>
                <enabled>true</enabled>
            </snapshots>
        </repository>
        <repository>
            <id>spring-milestones</id>
            <name>Spring Milestones</name>
            <url>http://repo.spring.io/milestone</url>
            <snapshots>
                <enabled>false</enabled>
            </snapshots>
        </repository>
    </repositories>
    <pluginRepositories>
        <pluginRepository>
            <id>spring-snapshots</id>
            <name>Spring Snapshots</name>
            <url>http://repo.spring.io/snapshot</url>
            <snapshots>
                <enabled>true</enabled>
            </snapshots>
        </pluginRepository>
        <pluginRepository>
            <id>spring-milestones</id>
            <name>Spring Milestones</name>
            <url>http://repo.spring.io/milestone</url>
            <snapshots>
                <enabled>false</enabled>
            </snapshots>
        </pluginRepository>
    </pluginRepositories>

</project>
```

I wonder what could be missing in my app? I followed the instruction from here [Using Spring Data JPA on Google Appengine](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15359784/using-spring-data-jpa-on-google-appengine)

Comment: If I comment out the @EnableAutoConfiguration I get: [INFO] WARNING: failed metricFilter: org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No bean named 'metricFilter' is defined

Comment: Here is the complete code: http://bit.ly/1i53oAq

Comment: In my case it was [spring-boot-starter-data-jpa](http://stackoverflow.com/a/37554576/234110)

Answer (score 194, accepted):

You haven't provided Spring Boot with enough information to auto-configure a `DataSource`. To do so, you'll need to add some properties to `application.properties` with the `spring.datasource` prefix. Take a look at [DataSourceProperties](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/blob/master/spring-boot-project/spring-boot-autoconfigure/src/main/java/org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/jdbc/DataSourceProperties.java) to see all of the properties that you can set.

You'll need to provide the appropriate url and driver class name:

```
spring.datasource.url = …
spring.datasource.driver-class-name = …
```

Comment: not sure what to put here I'm using DataNucleus + Google App Engine

Comment: @xybrek Just add application.properties file in your application and add the datasource properties in it.

Comment: spring.datasource.url = jdbc:mysql://localhost/abc
#spring.datasource.driverClassName = com.mysql.jdbc.Driver
spring.datasource.name=olabsenglishdb
spring.datasource.username=xxxx
spring.datasource.password=xxxx
spring.datasource.driver-class-name= com.mysql.jdbc.Driver
spring.jpa.database=mysql
spring.jpa.database-platform=org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect

Comment: I did the same, the code is working fine when i run the application in intellij but when i create a jar and run it using `java -jar myJar.jar` it is giving me same error.

Comment: What if one does want to configure the datasource on runtime?

Answer (score 121):

If you want to use embedded H2 database from Spring Boot starter add the below dependency to your pom file.

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.h2database</groupId>
        <artifactId>h2</artifactId>
        <version>1.3.156</version>
    </dependency>
```

But as mentioned in comments, the embedded H2 database keeps data in memory and doesn't stores it permanently.

Comment: I was having the same problem with spring-boot-starter-jdbc. Tried this suggestion and it fixed my problem.

Comment: This is not a real solution. H2 will not permanently save data as far as I'm aware.

Comment: @SARose - Of course it wont! It's an "in memory" database.

Comment: @user672009, incorrect.  H2 is not only an in memory database. See http://www.h2database.com/html/features.html. With that said, this is a poor solution to the problem.

Comment: I'm trying to build somebody's app and I get this "Cannot determine ... for database type NONE" error.  After trying other solutions, I try this one and it works.  The app was made to use two DBs, configured by properties.  I configured them, but got this error.  After I add the H2 dependency, no more errors.  The app uses the other DBs I specified, nothing ever goes to H2, AFAICT.  May be a side-effect of spring-boot or a problem in this app's design, but it requires H2 before it will start.  Since others have this problem, it can't be just this app.

Comment: This one is working , I was using a newer one 1.4.xx but it seems that other configuration is required to set that one up , at least in my Spring boot project

Comment: No need to have version since spring boot already included with version

Comment: Not a proper solution for problem of a main question, but if you're facing that issue during writing tests (like I did), then IMO this is pretty good solution.

Comment: H2 artifact in pom did solve the problem for me too. But I needed to work with different DB, So I replaced H2 artifact with postgresql artifact and it worked as well. The issue is that spring needs to know which DB it is and there is no default. So you just need to get the correct DB artifact into your pom file and that should resolve your issue

Answer (score 96):

I'd the same problem and excluding the DataSourceAutoConfiguration solved the problem.

```
@SpringBootApplication
@EnableAutoConfiguration(exclude={DataSourceAutoConfiguration.class})
public class RecommendationEngineWithCassandraApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(RecommendationEngineWithCassandraApplication.class, args);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks! could config it in `application.properties`, like `spring.main.web-environment=false`

Comment: I found `@EnableAutoConfiguration` in a non-SpringBootApplication class, and had to add the exclude there too.  TBH, I probably don't need `@EnableAutoConfiguration` there in the first place :/

Answer (score 67):

This worked for me (1.3.0.M5) :

```
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.jdbc.*;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.orm.jpa.*;

@Configuration
@EnableAutoConfiguration(exclude = {DataSourceAutoConfiguration.class, HibernateJpaAutoConfiguration.class})
public class Application {
```

Exclude both classes.

It did not work with

```
@SpringBootApplication(exclude = {DataSourceAutoConfiguration.class, HibernateJpaAutoConfiguration.class})
```

Comment: This one is for people who don't understand why they 'mysteriously' require database access in their application when they shouldn't(e.g when the database access is being handled by some other application and this one is just a 'client').

Answer (score 38):

You can add

```
spring.autoconfigure.exclude=org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.jdbc.DataSourceAutoConfiguration
```

to your `application.properties` file.

Comment: This is especially useful when you have multiple profiles and one of them is in-memory.

Comment: For me, I needed to exluse HibernateJpaAutoConfiguration also in order to work : spring.autoconfigure.exclude=org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.jdbc.DataSourceAutoConfiguration, org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.orm.jpa.HibernateJpaAutoConfiguration

Comment: worked perfectly fine in my case, where i was launching from command line

Answer (score 20):

Now that I look closer, I think that the DataSource problem is a red-herring. Boot's Hibernate auto-configuration is being triggered and that's what causing a DataSource to be required. Hibernate's on the classpath because you've got a dependency on `spring-boot-starter-data-jpa` which pulls in `hibernate-entitymanager`.

Update your `spring-boot-starter-data-jpa` dependency to exclude Hibernate:

```xml
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
    <exclusions>
        <exclusion>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-entitymanager</artifactId>
        </exclusion>
    </exclusions>
</dependency>
```

Comment: Error still the same :-(

Comment: Are you sure you've applied the exclusion properly? mvn dependency:tree will help you to check. With the exclusion in place the DataSource problem's gone for me (I now see "Type demo.core.entity.Resource is not a known managed type", but that's a separate issue)

Comment: Hi Andy does it mean you tested the actual project I posted? looks promising

Comment: Yes, that was with the project you posted. The only change I made was to add the Hibernate exclusion as described above.

Comment: Cool, it seems what you've compiled was the master branch, or the JPA branch?

Comment: and it seems 'mvn clean install' works fine, but did you try 'mvn appengine:devserver'?

Comment: This red herring is a red herring. The answer's above, relating to the missing H2 dependency.

Comment: Not in the OP's case. They were trying to use Datanucleus rather than Hibernate

Comment: after adding this i got entity manager factory could not be found because i have entity inside my class.

Comment: for a newer spring-boot-starter-data-jpa version, you need to exclude 'spring-boot-starter-jdbc'.  This works for me.

Answer (score 17):

From the [Spring manual](http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/boot-features-sql.html#boot-features-embedded-database-support).

> Spring Boot can auto-configure embedded H2, HSQL, and Derby databases. You don’t need to provide any connection URLs, simply include a build dependency to the embedded database that you want to use.
>
> For example, typical POM dependencies would be:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.hsqldb</groupId>
    <artifactId>hsqldb</artifactId>
    <scope>runtime</scope>
</dependency>
```

For me leaving out the spring-boot-starter-data-jpa dependency and just using the spring-boot-starter-jdbc dependency worked like a charm, as long as I had h2 (or hsqldb) included as dependencies.

Answer (score 9):

Spring boot will look for datasoure properties in application.properties file.

Please define it in application.properties or yml file

**application.properties**

```
spring.datasource.url=xxx
spring.datasource.username=xxx
spring.datasource.password=xxx
spring.datasource.driver-class-name=xxx
```

If you need your own configuration you could set your own profile and use the datasource values while bean creation.

Answer (score 7):

I don't if it is too late to answer. 
I could solve this issue by excluding DataSourceAutoConfiguration from spring boot.

Comment: Documentation on exluding found here: http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/using-boot-auto-configuration.html

Answer (score 5):

I faced this exception while I was doing APIs for ElasticSearch using Spring Data. I did the following and it worked.

```
@SpringDataApplication(exclude = {DataSourceAutoConfiguration.class, HibernateJpaAutoConfiguration.class})
```

Answer (score 3):

I solve my problem just adding **@AutoConfigureTestDatabase(replace=Replace.NONE)**

```
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@DataJpaTest
@AutoConfigureTestDatabase(replace=Replace.NONE)
public class TestClienteRepository {

}
```

Answer (score 3):

I had two dependencies with groupId of org.springframework.data, then I removed jpa and kept mongodb only , and it worked!

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.data</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-data-mongodb</artifactId>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.data</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-data-jpa</artifactId>
</dependency>
```

Answer (score 3):

I'd the similar problem and excluding the DataSourceAutoConfiguration and HibernateJpaAutoConfiguration solved the problem.

I have added these two lines in my application.properties file and it worked.

```
> spring.autoconfigure.exclude[0]=org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.jdbc.DataSourceAutoConfiguration
> spring.autoconfigure.exclude[1]=org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.orm.jpa.HibernateJpaAutoConfiguration
```

Comment: This worked for me as well. I've been fighting with a database connection issue with Java for an hour thanks @rajeev you made my day

Answer (score 2):

As this is one of the first topics returned in google for this error, I'll post what I did in case someone face the same issue..
I didn't want to exclude `DataSourceAutoConfiguration` neither use a memory database..

In my case I was setting the parameters as the other repliers said but the `application.properties` file was inside the wrong folder.. lol

So in case nothing like this works, check if the file is inside `src/main/resources`! In my case it was inside `src/main/resources/static`

Answer (score 2):

I got the error message in the title from `o.s.b.d.LoggingFailureAnalysisReporter` along with the message "APPLICATION FAILED TO START". It turned out that I hadn't added `-Dspring.profiles.active=dev` to my Eclipse debug configuration so I had no active profile.

Comment: Exactly my problem as well. Adding the flag to the VM arguments of the debug configuration (`Run -> Debug configurations... -> Maven build -> [build name] -> JRE -> VM arguments`)

Answer (score 2):

I too faced the same issue.

```
Cannot determine embedded database driver class for database type NONE.
```

In my case deleting the jar file from repository corresponding to the database fixes the issue. There was corrupted jar present in the repository which was causing the issue.

Answer (score 2):

Use this below dependency.

```
<dependency>
   <groupId>com.h2database</groupId>
   <artifactId>h2</artifactId>
   <scope>runtime</scope>
</dependency>
```

Comment: I didn't need a database and was getting this error.  I added this and it fixed it.

Answer (score 1):

In my case , I put it a maven dependency for org.jasig.cas in my pom that triggered a hibernate dependency and that caused Spring Boot to look for a datasource to auto-configure hibernate persistence.
I solved it by adding the com.h2database maven dependency as suggested by user672009. Thanks guys!

Answer (score 1):

Doing below works.

```
@EnableAutoConfiguration(exclude={DataSourceAutoConfiguration.class})
```

But If I wanted to have dataSource, I should not do the above configuration. 
The below link says that we need to all the properties in application.properties file. All the properties should start with 
`spring.datasource.*`

http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/common-application-properties.html

Answer (score 1):

Answer is very simple, SpringBoot will look for Embeddable database driver, If you didn't configure in any of your configuration in form of XML or Annotations, it will throws this exception.
Make the changes in your annotation like this

```
@EnableAutoConfiguration(exclude=DataSourceAutoConfiguration.class)
```

this will exclude the DataSourceAutoConfiguration.
And the Perfect Simple Coding completion would be work if you have properly configured your class.

```
    @Controller
    @EnableAutoConfiguration(exclude=DataSourceAutoConfiguration.class)
     public class SimpleController {
      @RequestMapping("/")
      @ResponseBody
       String home() {
        return "Hello World!";
       }public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        SpringApplication.run(SimpleController.class, args);
       }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

If you really need "spring-boot-starter-data-jpa" as your project dependency and at the same time you don't want to allow your app to access any database, you can simply exclude auto-configuration classes

```
@SpringBootApplication(exclude = DataSourceAutoConfiguration.class)
```

Answer (score 1):

I tried all the mentioned things above but could not resolve the issue. I am using SQLite and my SQLite file was in the resources directory.

a) **Set Up done for IDE**

I need to manually add below lines in the .classpath file of my project.

```
<classpathentry kind="src" path="resources"/>
<classpathentry kind="output" path="target/classes"/>
```

After that, I refreshed and Cleaned the project from MenuBar at the top. like Project->Clean->My Project Name.

After that, I run the project and problem resolved.

**application.properties** for my project is

```
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:sqlite:resources/apiusers.sqlite
spring.datasource.driver-class-name=org.sqlite.JDBC
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.dialect=com.enigmabridge.hibernate.dialect.SQLiteDialect
spring.datasource.username=
spring.datasource.password=
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=update
```

b) **Set Up done if Jar deployment throw same error**

You need to add following lines to your pom.xml

```
  <build>
        <resources>
        <resource>
            <directory>resources</directory>
            <targetPath>${project.build.outputDirectory}</targetPath>
            <includes>
                <include>application.properties</include>
            </includes>
        </resource>
    </resources>
</build>
```

May be it may help someone.

Answer (score 1):

if you do not have any database in your application simply disable the auto-config of datasource by adding below annotation.

```
@SpringBootApplication(exclude={DataSourceAutoConfiguration.class})
```

Answer (score 1):

The same to @Anas. I can run it in Eclipse, but when i use "java -jar ..." run it, it giving me this error. Then i find my java build path is wrong, it missing the folder “src/main/resources”, so, the application can't find application.properties. When i add the “src/main/resources” folder in java build path, it worked.

And, you need add "@PropertySource({"application.properties"})" in your Application class.

[Screenshot-1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lPQHX.png)

[Screenshot-2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2h59v.png)

Answer (score 1):

This is how I resolved this problem.

In my case: I had to configure the datasource for MySQL Server, which was an external Server.

As we all know, Spring boot has capability to auto-configure DataSource for embedded databases.

Thus, I realized that I had to disable datasource auto-configuration in order use my custom configuration.

As mentioned above by many, I disabled Automatic DataSource configuration of Spring Boot at application.properties

> spring.autoconfigure.exclude=org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.jdbc.DataSourceAutoConfiguration

I defined all hibernate configuration properties in a separate file: 
hibernate-mysql.properties

Then, I coded my own Custom Hibernate Configuration in following manner and it resolved the issue.

My way to configure the desired DataSource based on properties in a custom property file and populate your LocalSessionFactoryBean with your data source and other hibernate configuration.

**Hibernate Custom Configuration Class:-**
**---------------------------------------------------------**

[Hibernate Custom Configuration](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lZOXJ.png)

Answer (score 1):

In my case, using IDEA, after remove the **`out`** direcory, then everything return to normal. I just don't know why, but it worked out.

Answer (score 1):

Already enough of answers were posted. However, I'm posting what mistake i did and how i corrected it.

In my case, i had packaged my project as `pom` instead of `jar`

**pom.xml:**

```
...
 <packaging>pom</packaging>
...
```

Changed to:

```
...
 <packaging>jar</packaging>
...
```

It may helpful for someone with the same mistake.

Answer (score 0):

You can download the derby-10.10.1.1.jar from the [Maven Repository](http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.derby/derby/10.10.1.1) and place it in your WEB-INF/lib folder, like this Application/WEB-INF/lib/derby-10.10.1.1.jar.
Your embedded AnnotationConfigEmbeddedWebApplicationContext will pickup the database driver and your webserver will start running without any issues :-)

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Gradle, include right jar of driver as below:

```
compile("org.mongodb:mongo-java-driver:3.3.0")
```

Or if using Maven then do it in Maven style, it should solve your problem.

Answer (score 0):

To anybody coming to this thread after hours of banging your head against a wall.  I solved this error by changing

```
create table `group`(
    id char(19) primary key
);
```

to

```
create table if not exists `group`(
    id char(19) primary key
);
```

in my schema.sql file in the resources directory.

Answer (score 0):

Right click the project and select the following option Maven -> Update Project. This has solved my issue.

Answer (score 0):

Generally, such error occurs when you've used JPA and forget to add database connection. So, you must add database related dependencies in your application.

Though, you want to use JPA without connecting any external database then add hsqldb in your dependency.

I hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

My application file wasn't being read and Spring was trying to connect to an embedded H2 database (that wasn't added in the pom) instead. This was throwing the following error message:

> if you have database settings to be loaded from a particular profile
> you may need to activate it (no profiles are currently active).

Make sure that your application file is being read by following [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/33022827/3591888) question.

Answer (score 0):

If none of it works, try Making a Repository class as well as RepositoryInterface,
though a class of implementation should automatically be generated by spring boot,
this is what worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

In my case i had an empty application.properties file at `target\classes`.
I just deleted to fix the problem.

Answer (score -3):

Delete `C:\Users\admin\.IntelliJIdea2018.1\system\compile-server`