# AWS Beanstalk: Cannot determine embedded database driver class

Tags: amazon-web-services, spring-boot, amazon-elastic-beanstalk, amazon-dynamodb

I have a spring boot application which runs just fine on my local instance (through Intellij) but while deploying on AWS BEanstalk, the application throws the following error (sorry about the formatting. This is how spring generated the exception):

`org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.jdbc.DataSourceAutoConfig
uration$JdbcTemplateConfiguration': Injection of autowired dependencies failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationExcept
ion: Could not autowire field: private javax.sql.DataSource org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.jdbc.DataSourceAutoConfiguration$JdbcTemplateConfigur
ation.dataSource; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'dataSource' defined in cla
ss path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/jdbc/DataSourceAutoConfiguration$NonEmbeddedConfiguration.class]: Bean instantiation via factor
y method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [javax.sql.DataSource]: Factory method 
'dataSource' threw exception; nested exception is org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.jdbc.DataSourceProperties$DataSourceBeanCreationException: Cann
ot determine embedded database driver class for database type NONE. If you want an embedded database please put a supported one on the classpath. If you
 have database settings to be loaded from a particular profile you may need to active it (the profiles "aws" are currently active).`

**pom.xml**

```
<dependencyManagement>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-core</artifactId>
            <version>${jackson.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-annotations</artifactId>
            <version>${jackson.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-databind</artifactId>
            <version>${jackson.version}</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
</dependencyManagement>

<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-rest</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.amazonaws</groupId>
        <artifactId>aws-java-sdk-dynamodb</artifactId>
        <version>1.10.56</version>
    </dependency>

</dependencies>

<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        </plugin>

        <plugin>
            <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
            <configuration>
                <archive>
                    <manifest>
                        <mainClass>com.my.app.path.MyApplication</mainClass>
                    </manifest>
                </archive>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

**application.properties**

```
spring.profiles.active=aws
dynamodb.tablename=my_dynamodb_table
```

**application-aws.properties**

```
spring.profiles.active=aws
```

The application uses a table in dynamodb. Could this be because I might need to set permissions in AWS to allow beanstalk to talk to dynamodb? If so, please let me know how to do that.

My EC2 instance is `tomcat8` type.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the solution to my question on [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24074749/spring-boot-cannot-determine-embedded-database-driver-class-for-database-type). See the answer by @user672009.

Just add this to your pom.

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.h2database</groupId>
    <artifactId>h2</artifactId>
    <version>1.3.156</version>
</dependency>
```