# H2 embeded DB with spring boot error auto configuring

Tags: java, maven, spring-boot, jar, h2

i'm trying to use the H2 embedded DB with spring boot. But, it throws the following errors.

```
2016-10-19 22:05:25.818  INFO 14104 --- [           main] com.example.SpringDemoApplication        : Starting SpringDemoApplication on BOM1-LPMP12AS7U with PID 14104 (D:\workspace\eclipse\SpringDemo\target\classes started by e3028311 in D:\workspace\eclipse\SpringDemo)
2016-10-19 22:05:25.822  INFO 14104 --- [           main] com.example.SpringDemoApplication        : No active profile set, falling back to default profiles: default
2016-10-19 22:05:25.904  INFO 14104 --- [           main] ationConfigEmbeddedWebApplicationContext : Refreshing org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.AnnotationConfigEmbeddedWebApplicationContext@543e710e: startup date [Wed Oct 19 22:05:25 IST 2016]; root of context hierarchy
2016-10-19 22:05:27.609  INFO 14104 --- [           main] trationDelegate$BeanPostProcessorChecker : Bean 'org.springframework.transaction.annotation.ProxyTransactionManagementConfiguration' of type [class org.springframework.transaction.annotation.ProxyTransactionManagementConfiguration$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$ece75ca4] is not eligible for getting processed by all BeanPostProcessors (for example: not eligible for auto-proxying)
2016-10-19 22:05:28.474  INFO 14104 --- [           main] s.b.c.e.t.TomcatEmbeddedServletContainer : Tomcat initialized with port(s): 8080 (http)
2016-10-19 22:05:28.490  INFO 14104 --- [           main] o.apache.catalina.core.StandardService   : Starting service Tomcat
2016-10-19 22:05:28.491  INFO 14104 --- [           main] org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine  : Starting Servlet Engine: Apache Tomcat/8.0.37
2016-10-19 22:05:28.658  INFO 14104 --- [ost-startStop-1] o.a.c.c.C.[Tomcat].[localhost].[/]       : Initializing Spring embedded WebApplicationContext
2016-10-19 22:05:28.658  INFO 14104 --- [ost-startStop-1] o.s.web.context.ContextLoader            : Root WebApplicationContext: initialization completed in 2759 ms
2016-10-19 22:05:29.055  INFO 14104 --- [ost-startStop-1] o.s.b.c.e.ServletRegistrationBean        : Mapping servlet: 'dispatcherServlet' to [/]
2016-10-19 22:05:29.060  INFO 14104 --- [ost-startStop-1] o.s.b.c.embedded.FilterRegistrationBean  : Mapping filter: 'characterEncodingFilter' to: [/*]
2016-10-19 22:05:29.061  INFO 14104 --- [ost-startStop-1] o.s.b.c.embedded.FilterRegistrationBean  : Mapping filter: 'hiddenHttpMethodFilter' to: [/*]
2016-10-19 22:05:29.061  INFO 14104 --- [ost-startStop-1] o.s.b.c.embedded.FilterRegistrationBean  : Mapping filter: 'httpPutFormContentFilter' to: [/*]
2016-10-19 22:05:29.061  INFO 14104 --- [ost-startStop-1] o.s.b.c.embedded.FilterRegistrationBean  : Mapping filter: 'requestContextFilter' to: [/*]
2016-10-19 22:05:29.131  WARN 14104 --- [           main] ationConfigEmbeddedWebApplicationContext : Exception encountered during context initialization - cancelling refresh attempt: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.orm.jpa.HibernateJpaAutoConfiguration': Injection of autowired dependencies failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: private javax.sql.DataSource org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.orm.jpa.JpaBaseConfiguration.dataSource; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'dataSource' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/jdbc/DataSourceAutoConfiguration$NonEmbeddedConfiguration.class]: Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [javax.sql.DataSource]: Factory method 'dataSource' threw exception; nested exception is org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.jdbc.DataSourceProperties$DataSourceBeanCreationException: Cannot determine embedded database driver class for database type NONE. If you want an embedded database please put a supported one on the classpath. If you have database settings to be loaded from a particular profile you may need to active it (no profiles are currently active).
2016-10-19 22:05:29.146  INFO 14104 --- [           main] o.apache.catalina.core.StandardService   : Stopping service Tomcat
2016-10-19 22:05:29.169 ERROR 14104 --- [           main] o.s.boot.SpringApplication               : Application startup failed

org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.orm.jpa.HibernateJpaAutoConfiguration': Injection of autowired dependencies failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: private javax.sql.DataSource org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.orm.jpa.JpaBaseConfiguration.dataSource; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'dataSource' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/jdbc/DataSourceAutoConfiguration$NonEmbeddedConfiguration.class]: Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [javax.sql.DataSource]: Factory method 'dataSource' threw exception; nested exception is org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.jdbc.DataSourceProperties$DataSourceBeanCreationException: Cannot determine embedded database driver class for database type NONE. If you want an embedded database please put a supported one on the classpath. If you have database settings to be loaded from a particular profile you may need to active it (no profiles are currently active).
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessPropertyValues(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:334) ~[spring-beans-4.2.8.RELEASE.jar:4.2.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1218) ~[spring-beans-4.2.8.RELEASE.jar:4.2.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:543) ~[spring-beans-4.2.8.RELEASE.jar:4.2.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:482) ~[spring-beans-4.2.8.RELEASE.jar:4.2.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:306) ~[spring-beans-4.2.8.RELEASE.jar:4.2.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:230) ~[spring-beans-4.2.8.RELEASE.jar:4.2.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:302) ~[spring-beans-4.2.8.RELEASE.jar:4.2.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:197) ~[spring-beans-4.2.8.RELEASE.jar:4.2.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(ConstructorResolver.java:368) ~[spring-beans-4.2.8.RELEASE.jar:4.2.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1127) ~[spring-beans-4.2.8.RELEASE.jar:4.2.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1022) ~[spring-beans-4.2.8.RELEASE.jar:4.2.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:510) ~[spring-beans-4.2.8.RELEASE.jar:4.2.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:482) ~[spring-beans-4.2.8.RELEASE.jar:4.2.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:306) ~[spring-beans-4.2.8.RELEASE.jar:4.2.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:230) ~[spring-beans-4.2.8.RELEASE.jar:4.2.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:302) ~[spring-beans-4.2.8.RELEASE.jar:4.2.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:197) ~[spring-beans-4.2.8.RELEASE.jar:4.2.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.getBean(AbstractApplicationContext.java:1054) ~[spring-context-4.2.8.RELEASE.jar:4.2.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:829) ~[spring-context-4.2.8.RELEASE.jar:4.2.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:538) ~[spring-context-4.2.8.RELEASE.jar:4.2.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.refresh(EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.java:118) ~[spring-boot-1.3.8.RELEASE.jar:1.3.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:760) [spring-boot-1.3.8.RELEASE.jar:1.3.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.createAndRefreshContext(SpringApplication.java:360) [spring-boot-1.3.8.RELEASE.jar:1.3.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:306) [spring-boot-1.3.8.RELEASE.jar:1.3.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1185) [spring-boot-1.3.8.RELEASE.jar:1.3.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1174) [spring-boot-1.3.8.RELEASE.jar:1.3.8.RELEASE]
    at com.example.SpringDemoApplication.main(SpringDemoApplication.java:27) [classes/:na]
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: private javax.sql.DataSource org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.orm.jpa.JpaBaseConfiguration.dataSource; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'dataSource' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/jdbc/DataSourceAutoConfiguration$NonEmbeddedConfiguration.class]: Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [javax.sql.DataSource]: Factory method 'dataSource' threw exception; nested exception is org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.jdbc.DataSourceProperties$DataSourceBeanCreationException: Cannot determine embedded database driver class for database type NONE. If you want an embedded database please put a supported one on the classpath. If you have database settings to be loaded from a particular profile you may need to active it (no profiles are currently active).
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:573) ~[spring-beans-4.2.8.RELEASE.jar:4.2.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InjectionMetadata.inject(InjectionMetadata.java:88) ~[spring-beans-4.2.8.RELEASE.jar:4.2.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessPropertyValues(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:331) ~[spring-beans-4.2.8.RELEASE.jar:4.2.8.RELEASE]
    ... 26 common frames omitted
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'dataSource' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/jdbc/DataSourceAutoConfiguration$NonEmbeddedConfiguration.class]: Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [javax.sql.DataSource]: Factory method 'dataSource' threw exception; nested exception is org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.jdbc.DataSourceProperties$DataSourceBeanCreationException: Cannot determine embedded database driver class for database type NONE. If you want an embedded database please put a supported one on the classpath. If you have database settings to be loaded from a particular profile you may need to active it (no profiles are currently active).
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(ConstructorResolver.java:599) ~[spring-beans-4.2.8.RELEASE.jar:4.2.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1127) ~[spring-beans-4.2.8.RELEASE.jar:4.2.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1022) ~[spring-beans-4.2.8.RELEASE.jar:4.2.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:510) ~[spring-beans-4.2.8.RELEASE.jar:4.2.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:482) ~[spring-beans-4.2.8.RELEASE.jar:4.2.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:306) ~[spring-beans-4.2.8.RELEASE.jar:4.2.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:230) ~[spring-beans-4.2.8.RELEASE.jar:4.2.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:302) ~[spring-beans-4.2.8.RELEASE.jar:4.2.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:197) ~[spring-beans-4.2.8.RELEASE.jar:4.2.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.findAutowireCandidates(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1199) ~[spring-beans-4.2.8.RELEASE.jar:4.2.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1123) ~[spring-beans-4.2.8.RELEASE.jar:4.2.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1021) ~[spring-beans-4.2.8.RELEASE.jar:4.2.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:545) ~[spring-beans-4.2.8.RELEASE.jar:4.2.8.RELEASE]
    ... 28 common frames omitted
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [javax.sql.DataSource]: Factory method 'dataSource' threw exception; nested exception is org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.jdbc.DataSourceProperties$DataSourceBeanCreationException: Cannot determine embedded database driver class for database type NONE. If you want an embedded database please put a supported one on the classpath. If you have database settings to be loaded from a particular profile you may need to active it (no profiles are currently active).
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.SimpleInstantiationStrategy.instantiate(SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java:189) ~[spring-beans-4.2.8.RELEASE.jar:4.2.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(ConstructorResolver.java:588) ~[spring-beans-4.2.8.RELEASE.jar:4.2.8.RELEASE]
    ... 40 common frames omitted
Caused by: org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.jdbc.DataSourceProperties$DataSourceBeanCreationException: Cannot determine embedded database driver class for database type NONE. If you want an embedded database please put a supported one on the classpath. If you have database settings to be loaded from a particular profile you may need to active it (no profiles are currently active).
    at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.jdbc.DataSourceProperties.getDriverClassName(DataSourceProperties.java:180) ~[spring-boot-autoconfigure-1.3.8.RELEASE.jar:1.3.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.jdbc.DataSourceAutoConfiguration$NonEmbeddedConfiguration.dataSource(DataSourceAutoConfiguration.java:121) ~[spring-boot-autoconfigure-1.3.8.RELEASE.jar:1.3.8.RELEASE]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_91]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_91]
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_91]
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_91]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.SimpleInstantiationStrategy.instantiate(SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java:162) ~[spring-beans-4.2.8.RELEASE.jar:4.2.8.RELEASE]
    ... 41 common frames omitted

2016-10-19 22:05:29.173  INFO 14104 --- [           main] .b.l.ClasspathLoggingApplicationListener : Application failed to start with classpath: [file:/D:/workspace/eclipse/SpringDemo/target/classes/, file:/C:/Users/e3028311/.m2/repository/org/springframework/boot/spring-boot-starter-web/1.3.8.RELEASE/spring-boot-starter-web-1.3.8.RELEASE.jar, file:/C:/Users/e3028311/.m2/repository/org/springframework/boot/spring-boot-starter/1.3.8.RELEASE/spring-boot-starter-1.3.8.RELEASE.jar, file:/C:/Users/e3028311/.m2/repository/org/springframework/boot/spring-boot/1.3.8.RELEASE/spring-boot-1.3.8.RELEASE.jar, file:/C:/Users/e3028311/.m2/repository/org/springframework/boot/spring-boot-autoconfigure/1.3.8.RELEASE/spring-boot-autoconfigure-1.3.8.RELEASE.jar, file:/C:/Users/e3028311/.m2/repository/org/springframework/boot/spring-boot-starter-logging/1.3.8.RELEASE/spring-boot-starter-logging-1.3.8.RELEASE.jar, file:/C:/Users/e3028311/.m2/repository/ch/qos/logback/logback-classic/1.1.7/logback-classic-1.1.7.jar, file:/C:/Users/e3028311/.m2/repository/ch/qos/logback/logback-core/1.1.7/logback-core-1.1.7.jar, file:/C:/Users/e3028311/.m2/repository/org/slf4j/jul-to-slf4j/1.7.21/jul-to-slf4j-1.7.21.jar, file:/C:/Users/e3028311/.m2/repository/org/slf4j/log4j-over-slf4j/1.7.21/log4j-over-slf4j-1.7.21.jar, file:/C:/Users/e3028311/.m2/repository/org/yaml/snakeyaml/1.16/snakeyaml-1.16.jar, file:/C:/Users/e3028311/.m2/repository/org/springframework/boot/spring-boot-starter-tomcat/1.3.8.RELEASE/spring-boot-starter-tomcat-1.3.8.RELEASE.jar, file:/C:/Users/e3028311/.m2/repository/org/apache/tomcat/embed/tomcat-embed-core/8.0.37/tomcat-embed-core-8.0.37.jar, file:/C:/Users/e3028311/.m2/repository/org/apache/tomcat/embed/tomcat-embed-el/8.0.37/tomcat-embed-el-8.0.37.jar, file:/C:/Users/e3028311/.m2/repository/org/apache/tomcat/embed/tomcat-embed-logging-juli/8.0.37/tomcat-embed-logging-juli-8.0.37.jar, file:/C:/Users/e3028311/.m2/repository/org/apache/tomcat/embed/tomcat-embed-websocket/8.0.37/tomcat-embed-websocket-8.0.37.jar, file:/C:/Users/e3028311/.m2/repository/org/springframework/boot/spring-boot-starter-validation/1.3.8.RELEASE/spring-boot-starter-validation-1.3.8.RELEASE.jar, file:/C:/Users/e3028311/.m2/repository/org/hibernate/hibernate-validator/5.2.4.Final/hibernate-validator-5.2.4.Final.jar, file:/C:/Users/e3028311/.m2/repository/javax/validation/validation-api/1.1.0.Final/validation-api-1.1.0.Final.jar, file:/C:/Users/e3028311/.m2/repository/com/fasterxml/classmate/1.1.0/classmate-1.1.0.jar, file:/C:/Users/e3028311/.m2/repository/com/fasterxml/jackson/core/jackson-databind/2.6.7/jackson-databind-2.6.7.jar, file:/C:/Users/e3028311/.m2/repository/com/fasterxml/jackson/core/jackson-annotations/2.6.7/jackson-annotations-2.6.7.jar, file:/C:/Users/e3028311/.m2/repository/com/fasterxml/jackson/core/jackson-core/2.6.7/jackson-core-2.6.7.jar, file:/C:/Users/e3028311/.m2/repository/org/springframework/spring-web/4.2.8.RELEASE/spring-web-4.2.8.RELEASE.jar, file:/C:/Users/e3028311/.m2/repository/org/springframework/spring-aop/4.2.8.RELEASE/spring-aop-4.2.8.RELEASE.jar, file:/C:/Users/e3028311/.m2/repository/aopalliance/aopalliance/1.0/aopalliance-1.0.jar, file:/C:/Users/e3028311/.m2/repository/org/springframework/spring-beans/4.2.8.RELEASE/spring-beans-4.2.8.RELEASE.jar, file:/C:/Users/e3028311/.m2/repository/org/springframework/spring-context/4.2.8.RELEASE/spring-context-4.2.8.RELEASE.jar, file:/C:/Users/e3028311/.m2/repository/org/springframework/spring-webmvc/4.2.8.RELEASE/spring-webmvc-4.2.8.RELEASE.jar, file:/C:/Users/e3028311/.m2/repository/org/springframework/spring-expression/4.2.8.RELEASE/spring-expression-4.2.8.RELEASE.jar, file:/C:/Users/e3028311/.m2/repository/org/springframework/spring-core/4.2.8.RELEASE/spring-core-4.2.8.RELEASE.jar, file:/C:/Users/e3028311/.m2/repository/org/springframework/boot/spring-boot-starter-data-jpa/1.3.8.RELEASE/spring-boot-starter-data-jpa-1.3.8.RELEASE.jar, file:/C:/Users/e3028311/.m2/repository/org/springframework/boot/spring-boot-starter-aop/1.3.8.RELEASE/spring-boot-starter-aop-1.3.8.RELEASE.jar, file:/C:/Users/e3028311/.m2/repository/org/aspectj/aspectjweaver/1.8.9/aspectjweaver-1.8.9.jar, file:/C:/Users/e3028311/.m2/repository/org/hibernate/hibernate-entitymanager/4.3.11.Final/hibernate-entitymanager-4.3.11.Final.jar, file:/C:/Users/e3028311/.m2/repository/org/jboss/logging/jboss-logging/3.3.0.Final/jboss-logging-3.3.0.Final.jar, file:/C:/Users/e3028311/.m2/repository/org/jboss/logging/jboss-logging-annotations/1.2.0.Beta1/jboss-logging-annotations-1.2.0.Beta1.jar, file:/C:/Users/e3028311/.m2/repository/org/hibernate/hibernate-core/4.3.11.Final/hibernate-core-4.3.11.Final.jar, file:/C:/Users/e3028311/.m2/repository/antlr/antlr/2.7.7/antlr-2.7.7.jar, file:/C:/Users/e3028311/.m2/repository/org/jboss/jandex/1.1.0.Final/jandex-1.1.0.Final.jar, file:/C:/Users/e3028311/.m2/repository/dom4j/dom4j/1.6.1/dom4j-1.6.1.jar, file:/C:/Users/e3028311/.m2/repository/xml-apis/xml-apis/1.0.b2/xml-apis-1.0.b2.jar, file:/C:/Users/e3028311/.m2/repository/org/hibernate/common/hibernate-commons-annotations/4.0.5.Final/hibernate-commons-annotations-4.0.5.Final.jar, file:/C:/Users/e3028311/.m2/repository/org/hibernate/javax/persistence/hibernate-jpa-2.1-api/1.0.0.Final/hibernate-jpa-2.1-api-1.0.0.Final.jar, file:/C:/Users/e3028311/.m2/repository/org/javassist/javassist/3.18.1-GA/javassist-3.18.1-GA.jar, file:/C:/Users/e3028311/.m2/repository/javax/transaction/javax.transaction-api/1.2/javax.transaction-api-1.2.jar, file:/C:/Users/e3028311/.m2/repository/org/springframework/data/spring-data-jpa/1.9.5.RELEASE/spring-data-jpa-1.9.5.RELEASE.jar, file:/C:/Users/e3028311/.m2/repository/org/springframework/data/spring-data-commons/1.11.5.RELEASE/spring-data-commons-1.11.5.RELEASE.jar, file:/C:/Users/e3028311/.m2/repository/org/springframework/spring-orm/4.2.8.RELEASE/spring-orm-4.2.8.RELEASE.jar, file:/C:/Users/e3028311/.m2/repository/org/springframework/spring-tx/4.2.8.RELEASE/spring-tx-4.2.8.RELEASE.jar, file:/C:/Users/e3028311/.m2/repository/org/slf4j/slf4j-api/1.7.21/slf4j-api-1.7.21.jar, file:/C:/Users/e3028311/.m2/repository/org/slf4j/jcl-over-slf4j/1.7.21/jcl-over-slf4j-1.7.21.jar, file:/C:/Users/e3028311/.m2/repository/org/springframework/spring-aspects/4.2.8.RELEASE/spring-aspects-4.2.8.RELEASE.jar, file:/C:/Users/e3028311/.m2/repository/org/springframework/boot/spring-boot-starter-jdbc/1.3.8.RELEASE/spring-boot-starter-jdbc-1.3.8.RELEASE.jar, file:/C:/Users/e3028311/.m2/repository/org/apache/tomcat/tomcat-jdbc/8.0.37/tomcat-jdbc-8.0.37.jar, file:/C:/Users/e3028311/.m2/repository/org/apache/tomcat/tomcat-juli/8.0.37/tomcat-juli-8.0.37.jar, file:/C:/Users/e3028311/.m2/repository/org/springframework/spring-jdbc/4.2.8.RELEASE/spring-jdbc-4.2.8.RELEASE.jar, file:/C:/Users/e3028311/.m2/repository/com/h2database/h2/1.4.192/h2-1.4.192.jar]
```

Below is my POM

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>com.example</groupId>
    <artifactId>SpringDemo</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>jar</packaging>

    <name>SpringDemo</name>
    <description>Demo project for Spring Boot</description>

    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>1.3.8.RELEASE</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>

    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <project.reporting.outputEncoding>UTF-8</project.reporting.outputEncoding>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>


        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-jdbc</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.h2database</groupId>
            <artifactId>h2</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>


</project>
```

Below is my main class

```
package com.example;



import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.EnableAutoConfiguration;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;


@SpringBootApplication
@EnableAutoConfiguration
public class SpringDemoApplication {


    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(SpringDemoApplication.class, args);


    }


}
```

Previously, I had problems running even simple Spring boot application on my eclipse. But, worked fine on IntelliJ. Then I installed Spring Suite on Eclipse, after which embedded tomcat started working. But now, Database configuration is having problems. Please assist. Where am I going wrong?

Please view the [Structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Fbjpd.png) here.

Comment: duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24074749/spring-boot-cannot-determine-embedded-database-driver-class-for-database-type

Comment: have you tried cleaning up the project? embedded DB work with default configurations, no need to have the url,user,pass in application.properties unless overridden

Comment: Also it wouldn't hurt if you updated your S,B parent version <version>1.4.1.RELEASE</version>

Comment: @Georgesvanhoutte , SB ver updated. Still same error.

Comment: @Saravana, the above stacktrace was without any configurations.

Comment: @Rakz did you check maven-dependencies, h2 driver present?

Comment: @Saravana, yes. h2-1.4.192.jar is present.

Comment: @Rakz could you post main class code where you have annotated `SpringBootApplication`

Comment: @Saravana, added.

Comment: Also, post your app structure tree. jst to see if you have thet src/main/java src/main/resource

Comment: @Georgesvanhoutte, added

Comment: ok, there is a folder named "maven dependencies". Open it a see if your h2 db jar file is there or not.

Comment: Yes having h2-1.4.192.jar

Comment: @Saravana pls find code here https://app.assembla.com/spaces/rakz-project/subversion/source/HEAD/SpringDemo

Comment: @Georgesvanhoutte, you too.

Comment: Try this official code https://spring.io/guides/gs/accessing-data-jpa/ from sping boot : https://github.com/spring-guides/gs-accessing-data-jpa.git

Comment: @Rakz you code looks good, but I see some project errors in the snap attached, could you post the errors

Comment: @Saravana, it's resolved now. It was for updating project configurations by selecting Maven -> Update Project. what else is causing the trouble?

Comment: You don't need the jdbc maven dependency, as said in documentation: spring-jdbc it’s pulled in transitively via spring-boot-starter-data-jpa (http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/boot-features-sql.html)

Comment: @Rakz see my second comment, I told you to clean up the project :)

Answer (score 20):

I've got the same problem and I have found that it is caused by corrupted JAR files of H2 dependencies. [Refer to this link about corrupted jars](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41914842/3128926)

What you have to do is to delete the h2 related jar files in your .m2 maven local repository. For example I've deleted the following directory;

```
C:\Users\<user>\.m2\repository\com\h2database\
```

## Detailed Explanation

#### A - Clean the project

I have made a maven clean, all the build binaries deleted the output is as follows, nothing speacial;

```
D:\SpringSTS\sts-tezgah\conquisitio>mvn clean
[INFO] Scanning for projects...
[INFO]
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Building conquisitio 0.0.1-SNAPSHOT
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO]
[INFO] --- maven-clean-plugin:2.5:clean (default-clean) @ conquisitio ---
[INFO] Deleting D:\SpringSTS\sts-tezgah\conquisitio\target
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD SUCCESS
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 0.825 s
[INFO] Finished at: 2017-10-07T20:20:14+02:00
[INFO] Final Memory: 8M/155M
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

#### B - Run mvn install and check for possible errors

Here the output (I've cut it by half) of the **mvn install** command. You can see that there are the "**invalid LOC header (bad signature)**" warnings which means the related **.jar** files are corrupted;

```
D:\SpringSTS\sts-tezgah\conquisitio>mvn install
[INFO] Scanning for projects...
[INFO]
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Building conquisitio 0.0.1-SNAPSHOT
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO]
[INFO] --- maven-resources-plugin:2.6:resources (default-resources) @ conquisitio ---
[INFO] Using 'UTF-8' encoding to copy filtered resources.
[INFO] Copying 1 resource
[INFO] Copying 60 resources
[INFO]
[INFO] --- maven-compiler-plugin:3.1:compile (default-compile) @ conquisitio ---
[INFO] Changes detected - recompiling the module!
[INFO] Compiling 4 source files to D:\SpringSTS\sts-tezgah\conquisitio\target\classes
[WARNING] error reading C:\Users\Levent\.m2\repository\com\h2database\h2\1.4.190\h2-1.4.190.jar; invalid LOC header (bad signature)
[INFO]
[INFO] --- maven-resources-plugin:2.6:testResources (default-testResources) @ conquisitio ---
[INFO] Using 'UTF-8' encoding to copy filtered resources.
[INFO] skip non existing resourceDirectory D:\SpringSTS\sts-tezgah\conquisitio\src\test\resources
[INFO]
[INFO] --- maven-compiler-plugin:3.1:testCompile (default-testCompile) @ conquisitio ---
[INFO] Changes detected - recompiling the module!
[INFO] Compiling 1 source file to D:\SpringSTS\sts-tezgah\conquisitio\target\test-classes
[WARNING] error reading C:\Users\Levent\.m2\repository\com\h2database\h2\1.4.190\h2-1.4.190.jar; invalid LOC header (bad signature)
[INFO]
[INFO] --- maven-surefire-plugin:2.18.1:test (default-test) @ conquisitio ---
[INFO] Surefire report directory: D:\SpringSTS\sts-tezgah\conquisitio\target\surefire-reports
```

So, important warnings are as below;

```
[WARNING] error reading C:\Users\Levent\.m2\repository\com\h2database\h2\1.4.190\h2-1.4.190.jar; invalid LOC header (bad signature)

[WARNING] error reading C:\Users\Levent\.m2\repository\com\h2database\h2\1.4.190\h2-1.4.190.jar; invalid LOC header (bad signature)
```

Both imply the h2database jars and because these jars are corrupted, spring boot cannot load the related classes.

#### C - Solution

Simply delete the related dependencies in your maven cache that which appear in the **mvn install** command output.

Delete everything under;

```
C:\Users\Levent\.m2\repository\com\h2database\
```

#### D - Result

```
Maven automatically downloads the related jar files and project is running ok with the new uncorrupted jar files;

D:\SpringSTS\sts-tezgah\conquisitio>mvn clean install
[INFO] Scanning for projects...
[INFO]
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Building conquisitio 0.0.1-SNAPSHOT
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
Downloading: https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/com/h2database/h2/1.4.190/h2-1.4.190.pom
Downloaded: https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/com/h2database/h2/1.4.190/h2-1.4.190.pom (962 B at 991 B/s)
Downloading: https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/com/h2database/h2/1.4.190/h2-1.4.190.jar
Downloaded: https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/com/h2database/h2/1.4.190/h2-1.4.190.jar (1.7 MB at 1.5 MB/s)
[INFO]
[INFO] --- maven-clean-plugin:2.5:clean (default-clean) @ conquisitio ---
[INFO] Deleting D:\SpringSTS\sts-tezgah\conquisitio\target
[INFO]
[INFO] --- maven-resources-plugin:2.6:resources (default-resources) @ conquisitio ---
[INFO] Using 'UTF-8' encoding to copy filtered resources.
[INFO] Copying 1 resource
[INFO] Copying 60 resources
[INFO]
[INFO] --- maven-compiler-plugin:3.1:compile (default-compile) @ conquisitio ---
[INFO] Changes detected - recompiling the module!
[INFO] Compiling 4 source files to D:\SpringSTS\sts-tezgah\conquisitio\target\classes
[INFO]
[INFO] --- maven-resources-plugin:2.6:testResources (default-testResources) @ conquisitio ---
[INFO] Using 'UTF-8' encoding to copy filtered resources.
[INFO] skip non existing resourceDirectory D:\SpringSTS\sts-tezgah\conquisitio\src\test\resources
[INFO]
[INFO] --- maven-compiler-plugin:3.1:testCompile (default-testCompile) @ conquisitio ---
[INFO] Changes detected - recompiling the module!
[INFO] Compiling 1 source file to D:\SpringSTS\sts-tezgah\conquisitio\target\test-classes
[INFO]
[INFO] --- maven-surefire-plugin:2.18.1:test (default-test) @ conquisitio ---
[INFO] Surefire report directory: D:\SpringSTS\sts-tezgah\conquisitio\target\surefire-reports

-------------------------------------------------------
 T E S T S
-------------------------------------------------------
Running com.levent.conquisitio.AppTest
Tests run: 1, Failures: 0, Errors: 0, Skipped: 0, Time elapsed: 0.003 sec - in com.levent.conquisitio.AppTest

Results :

Tests run: 1, Failures: 0, Errors: 0, Skipped: 0

[INFO]
[INFO] --- maven-jar-plugin:2.5:jar (default-jar) @ conquisitio ---
[INFO] Building jar: D:\SpringSTS\sts-tezgah\conquisitio\target\conquisitio-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar
[INFO]
[INFO] --- spring-boot-maven-plugin:1.3.1.RELEASE:repackage (default) @ conquisitio ---
[INFO]
[INFO] --- maven-install-plugin:2.5.2:install (default-install) @ conquisitio ---
[INFO] Installing D:\SpringSTS\sts-tezgah\conquisitio\target\conquisitio-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar to C:\Users\Levent\.m2\repository\com\levent\conquisitio\0.0.1-SNAPSHOT\conquisitio-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar
[INFO] Installing D:\SpringSTS\sts-tezgah\conquisitio\pom.xml to C:\Users\Levent\.m2\repository\com\levent\conquisitio\0.0.1-SNAPSHOT\conquisitio-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.pom
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD SUCCESS
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 9.823 s
[INFO] Finished at: 2017-10-07T20:21:42+02:00
[INFO] Final Memory: 30M/213M
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Answer (score 2):

Have you got something like,

```
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:h2:mem:persondb
spring.datasource.username=sa
spring.datasource.password=
spring.datasource.driver-class-name=org.h2.Driver
```

in your application.properties file?

Comment: embedded DB works with default auto configurations, without this config also it would work

Comment: Adding these in properties file gives me the following error

Comment: Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Cannot load driver class: org.h2.Driver

Answer (score 2):

Please make sure there was no tailing space in each configuration line in `application.properties` file.

If you have any space on the right side of `org.h2.Driver` like below, delete them and it will run without problems.

`spring.datasource.driverClassName=org.h2.Driver`

I found a similar problem when copying the content from the tutorial website into my Spring boot `applicaiton.properties`.

Answer (score 1):

Try the below H2 configurations in your application.properties. Although Spring boot provides reasonable defaults, you can try tweaking the below these configurations  and it might be easy to switch to someother db for higher environments.

```
### Enable H2 Console Access 
spring.h2.console.enabled=true
spring.h2.console.path=/h2-console

### Define H2 Datasource configurations
spring.datasource.platform=h2
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:h2:mem:yourDB
spring.datasource.username=yourUser
spring.datasource.password=yourPwd
spring.datasource.driver-class-name=org.h2.Driver
```

Answer (score 0):

If the above Solution are not working in Your case
Try the below in application.properties

```
                  spring.h2.console.enabled=true
                  spring.datasource.platform=h2
                  spring.jpa.show-sql=true
```

Answer (score -1):

You have to explicitly add h2 dependency in your `pom.xml`:

```xml
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.h2database</groupId>
    <artifactId>h2</artifactId>
    <scope>runtime</scope>
</dependency>
```

or in `build.gradle`:

```
runtimeOnly "com.h2database:h2"
```

And you need to define the dialect/platform:

```yaml
spring:
  datasource:
    url: jdbc:h2:mem:testdb
    driverClassName: org.h2.Driver
    username: sa
    password: password
  jpa:
    database.platform: org.hibernate.dialect.H2Dialect
    show-sql: true
```

or in its corresponding form as properties in `application.properties`