# spring-boot configure hibernate-ogm for MongoDB

Tags: mongodb, hibernate, spring-boot, hibernate-ogm

---

APPLICATION FAILED TO START

---

Description:

Cannot determine embedded database driver class for database type NONE

Action:

If you want an embedded database please put a supported one on the classpath. If you have database settings to be loaded from a particular profile you may need to active it (the profiles "local" are currently active).

2016-11-10 18:36:52.335 ERROR 1288 --- [           main] o.s.test.context.TestContextManager      : Caught exception while allowing TestExecutionListener [org.springframework.test.context.web.ServletTestExecutionListener@d83da2e] to prepare test instance [com.example.DemoApplicationTests@1f68e4e8]

java.lang.IllegalStateException: Failed to load ApplicationContext
    at org.springframework.test.context.cache.DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.loadContext(DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.java:124) ~[spring-test-4.3.4.RELEASE.jar:4.3.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.test.context.support.DefaultTestContext.getApplicationContext(DefaultTestContext.java:83) ~[spring-test-4.3.4.RELEASE.jar:4.3.4.RELEASE]

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Spring Boot - Cannot determine embedded database driver class for database type NONE](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24074749/spring-boot-cannot-determine-embedded-database-driver-class-for-database-type)