# Cannot determine embedded database driver class for database type NONE with Redis in Spring Boot

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, redis

I use Spring Boot and redis. I added in `pom.xml`:

```
 <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-redis</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.data</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-data-redis</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
  </dependency>
```

And created class RedisConfig, which contains Beans `JedisConnectionFactory jedisConnectionFactory` and `RedisTemplate< String, Object > redisTemplate()`.

When I run application, I get error:

```
***************************
APPLICATION FAILED TO START
***************************

Description:

Cannot determine embedded database driver class for database type NONE

Action:

If you want an embedded database please put a supported one on the classpath. If you have database settings to be loaded from a particular profile you may need to active it (no profiles are currently active).
```

I don't use a embeded redis. Redis work on my computer on localhost.

`application.properties`:

```
spring.redis.host=localhost
spring.redis.port=6379
```

Why there is this error?

Comment: Have you tried what was suggested here - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24074749/spring-boot-cannot-determine-embedded-database-driver-class-for-database-type?rq=1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a couple of issues:

1. `spring-boot-starter-redis` is deprecated. Use `spring-boot-starter-data-redis` instead.
2. **Remove** the `spring-boot-starter-data-jpa` dependency. Spring Data Redis does not support JPA and it's not needed. This is actually causing your error.