# dependency throws Cannot determine embedded database driver class for database type NONE

Tags: hibernate, maven, spring-boot, docx4j

after including docx4j in pom.xml I'm getting "Cannot determine embedded database driver class for database type NONE" in maven build.
I already have datasource configured in my application.yml which works fine before adding docx4j. 
I suspect some dependency of docx4j is causing this error. but not able to find which is causing.

appreciate any help with this.

here is the error log:

> 2017-08-30 15:50:02.189  WARN 8787 --- [  restartedMain] ationConfigEmbeddedWebApplicationContext : Exception encountered during context initialization - cancelling refresh attempt: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.flyway.FlywayAutoConfiguration$FlywayConfiguration': Bean instantiation via constructor failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.flyway.FlywayAutoConfiguration$FlywayConfiguration$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$9e5ba179]: Constructor threw exception; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'dataSource' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/jdbc/DataSourceConfiguration$Tomcat.class]: Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.DataSource]: Factory method 'dataSource' threw exception; nested exception is org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.jdbc.DataSourceProperties$DataSourceBeanCreationException: Cannot determine embedded database driver class for database type NONE. If you want an embedded database please put a supported one on the classpath. If you have database settings to be loaded from a particular profile you may need to active it (no profiles are currently active).
>   2017-08-30 15:50:02.193  INFO 8787 --- [  restartedMain] o.apache.catalina.core.StandardService   : Stopping service Tomcat
>   2017-08-30 15:50:02.227  WARN 8787 --- [  restartedMain] o.s.boot.SpringApplication               : Error handling failed (Error creating bean with name 'delegatingApplicationListener' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/security/config/annotation/web/configuration/WebSecurityConfiguration.class]: BeanPostProcessor before instantiation of bean failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'metaDataSourceAdvisor': Cannot resolve reference to bean 'methodSecurityMetadataSource' while setting constructor argument; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'org.springframework.security.config.annotation.method.configuration.GlobalMethodSecurityConfiguration': Initialization of bean failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No bean named 'org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.importRegistry' available)
>   2017-08-30 15:50:02.233 ERROR 8787 --- [  restartedMain] o.s.b.d.LoggingFailureAnalysisReporter   :

---

APPLICATION FAILED TO START

---

Comment: You probably did more than just adding a dependency. Does the error goes away if you remove that single dependency (and only that?)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Spring Boot - Cannot determine embedded database driver class for database type NONE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24074749/spring-boot-cannot-determine-embedded-database-driver-class-for-database-type)