# Weird spring boot datasource error on start

Tags: database, spring-boot, configuration

I am getting weird Spring Boot error – Cannot determine embedded database driver class for database type NONE.
This application does not use database but has a dependency in external jar file which has the JPA dependency.
I am excluding `DataSourceAutoConfiguration` in the `SpringBootApplication` class.

```
@SpringBootApplication
@EnableAutoConfiguration(exclude={DataSourceAutoConfiguration.class})
public class SpringBatchHelloWorldApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(SpringBatchHelloWorldApplication.class, args);
    }
}
```

Comment: Try excluding Transaction Manager and HibernateJpa as well, Like `@EnableAutoConfiguration(exclude = {DataSourceAutoConfiguration.class, DataSourceTransactionManagerAutoConfiguration.class, HibernateJpaAutoConfiguration.class})
`

Comment: This might help (read Andy Wilkinson's answer): https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24074749/spring-boot-cannot-determine-embedded-database-driver-class-for-database-type